# How often the ether is deposited in my wallet when pool mining?

Tags: mining, ether, ethos

I am using ethOS and using 6 gpus. And i have a wallet with Jaxx. My question is when or how often does ether is deposited in my wallet, when i do pool mining. I have started mining since yesterday evening and it's around 22 hours mining now.

Comment: You should ask that kind of question to the pool operators. Each pool has its own policy.

Comment: It also depends on what you're contributing to the pool. Your cut of the rewards will reflect your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check with the pool miner. Typically, you can set your payout to be between 0.05 - 10 ETH for something like ethermine. You will have to go to the miner dashboard and check the settings. The amount produced depends on your hardware and Hashrate, which will also be viewable at the mining pool website.